# How can I set logstash conf when different logs input from the same thirty-party equipment

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

The thirty-party equipment has different logs when a user use differnet commands .
EX:
log A

```
Jun  2 16:45:49 host-A; rule='a', type='a', pattern='a', actions_taken='a', event_data='a'
```

log b

```
Jun 2 16:52:19 host-A; event='bbb',  user='sss',  com='111'
```

They don't have the same field when users  use differnet commands .

The gork  can't only uses  one pattern to parse log.

How can I set grok to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use grok to parse everything up to the semi-colon, then use a kv filter to parse the rest.